# T-SQL go through Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Column1     Column2   Column3
04/07/2019    1
04/08/2019    2
04/09/2019    8
04/10/2019    9
04/11/2019    15
04/12/2019    16
04/13/2019    5
04/14/2019    6 
04/15/2019    8
04/16/2019    9 
04/17/2019    10 
04/18/2019    11  
04/19/2019    5 
04/20/2019    5 
04/21/2019    8    
04/22/2019    8 
04/23/2019    9 
04/24/2019    10 
04/25/2019    11  
04/26/2019    12 
04/27/2019    10
```

I need to find out a way to iterate through the values in column one and identify weeks which should start from Saturday - Sunday. So, in this example one iteration should be from the 14 - 20th. Or another iteration would be from the 7th through the 13th which is Saturday - Sunday. Then After identifying each week, I need to do some calculation on the other columns.The calculation would be updating Column3 if the total amount for Column2 within 1 week (Based on Column1 Saturday to Sunday) exceeds 40 or not. Then the same for the next iteration of week (Saturday - Sunday).

Desired Results:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3
04/07/2019    1        56
04/08/2019    2        56
04/09/2019    8        56
04/10/2019    9        56
04/11/2019    15       56
04/12/2019    16       56
04/13/2019    5        56
04/14/2019    6        54
04/15/2019    8        54
04/16/2019    9        54
04/17/2019    10       54
04/18/2019    11       54
04/19/2019    5        54
04/20/2019    5        54
04/21/2019    8        68
04/22/2019    8        68
04/23/2019    9        68
04/24/2019    10       68
04/25/2019    11       68
04/26/2019    12       68
04/27/2019    10       68
```

Please note: The data can range from 3 weeks to a few month. So, the code needs to capture the weeks for any specific range.

Comment: A cursor is almost never the appropriate solution, and indeed it is not in this case either. Some combination of `DATEPART(WEEK, Column1)` and `GROUP BY` should do what you want.

Comment: You do not need cursors for this.  But provide your desired results (and set up some sort of db fiddle as well) to clarify the question.

Comment: Sure, revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datepart()` to get the week of a date. You can then use the week to partition by in a windowed `sum()`. From there you can `UPDATE` the table joining a derived table that gets the sum like mentioned before. To make sure the week begins on Sunday issue a `SET DATEFIRST 7` before the `UPDATE`.

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
UPDATE t1
       SET t1.column3 = t3.column3
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.column1,
                               sum(t2.column2) OVER (PARTITION BY datepart(week, t2.column1)) column3
                               FROM elbat t2) t3
                       ON t3.column1 = t1.column1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4626178e4a81a977161aad9ca54717e7)

Comment: Thank you very much! how would this work if the start date from one of the ranges starts at the middle of the week. For instance, instead of the 7th it starts at 10th. So, it should do a range from 10th - 13th. instead of 7th through the 13th. Reason being sometimes the start and end date do not exactly start on a Saturday and end on a Sunday.

Comment: `datepart()` gets the week of the day independent of the existence of other days of that week in the table. If there are only three days of a week the sum is build over the data of these three days.